# ActiveAdmin - Removing Delete admin user option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to get rid of the option so an admin is not able to delete themselves.

Currently, as the picture shows, the admin is able to delete themselves.

I am unsure on how to go about this? I inspected my system and I can see the code for ActiveAdmin layout. However, I am unable to view this.

Remove admin user button:

[image]

app/admin/admin_user.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

I added:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyUser do
  config.remove_action_item(:destroy)
end
```

As suggested, I have added the code but I am still receiving the "Delete admin user" button.

Comment: Please have a look at https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#disabling-actions-on-a-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to remove it.

One way to remove it with `config` variable in your `active_admin` resource file like

```
    ActiveAdmin.register MyUser do
        config.remove_action_item(:destroy)
        ...
    end
```

Otherwise you can skip this action via `actions` method like:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register MyUser do
      actions :all, except: [:destroy]
      ...
    end
```

ActiveAdmin resource files will be in `app/admin` directory in the code. For example `app/admin/admin_users.rb`

Comment: What file would I put this in? Config/initializer/active_admin.rb ? I tried putting the code in there but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Aah no, you have to put this code inside your active admin resource file, ex: `app/admin/admin_users.rb` in your case. It is generated when you setup the active admin via `rails g active_admin:install` command

Comment: I have added as suggested but it still isn't making any changes. I even restarted the server

Comment: Add `config.remove_action_item(:destroy)` right after `ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do`